# Identifier not found convertToHSL

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting an error identifier not found when I call convertToHSL(c1) in the main method. I dont understand what the issue with my code is. Please help. My code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "q3.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Color c1(1,1,1);
    HSL h=convertToHSL(c1);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

Color::Color(){}
Color::Color(float r,float g,float b){
    this->r=r;
    this->g=g;
    this->b=b;
}

Color::~Color(void){}

Color Color::operator+(Color c) {
    return Color(r*c.r,g*c.g,b*c.b);
}

Color Color::operator*(float s) {
    return Color(s*r,s*g,s*b);
}

HSL::HSL() {}
HSL::HSL(float h,float s,float l) {
    this->h=h;
    this->s=s;
    this->l=l;
}

HSL::~HSL(void){}





HSL convertToHSL(Color const& c) {
    return HSL(0,0,0);
```

Comment: Is convertToHSL declared in header file?

Answer (score 0):

If `convertToHSL` is not declared it is unknown on main(): replace main() on the end of the file underneath of all another functions.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you call `convertToHSL` (in `main`) your compiler simply doesn't know it exists, since it hasn't *"seen"* it yet (it has not been declared yet).

So in order to be able to call this function from `main`, either move the definition of `convertHSL` above main, or at least pre-declare it (without defining it) above main. Or, if it is to be used from other files, too, put its declaration into a header file (and its definition maybe into a seperate source file or with an `inline` specifier directly into the header file).

But if all this doesn't tell you much, you should delve a little deeper into the basics of C++.